# AS3: Messed up order of loading from an XML list

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, loader

So I'm trying to load up a group of thumbnails like the many times before, but this time their order of showing up is completely messed up, I can't find out WHY!!

```
function thumbsLoader(): void {
    for (var i: uint = 0; i < VideosTotal; i++) {
        thumbURL = VideoList[i].@THUMB_URL;
        thumbLoader = new Loader();
        thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(thumbURL));
        thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, viewThumbs);
        thumbLoader.name = i.toString();
    }
}

function viewThumbs(e: Event): void {
    thumb = e.target.loader;
    trace(thumb.name);
}
```

The trace function outputs :
13
11
6
20
18
4
14
16
7
17
2
1
15
9
0
8
22
3
12
10
5
19
21

instead of in increasing order... what can be wrong ?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Their loading order is purely based off of the files size. You basically telling all the files to load at once and it's a race to see who gets done first.

Comment: @AndrewSellenrick I've loaded pictures the same way before and it never happened, how to fix it this time??

Comment: Could have just been a coincidence? Are you needing access to them in order after they are all done?

Comment: @AndrewSellenrick maybe. I need to add them to the stage one by one in order at the viewThumbs function.. currently they are being added to the same order we get from the trace function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading file with Loader is performing **asynchronously**. Generally, it doesn't a problem and no need to fix it. But if you must have strict order of loading you can build a chain of Loaders. It may looks like this:

```
private var thumbIndex:uint = 0;

private function loadImage(index:uint):void
{
    thumbURL = VideoList[index].@THUMB_URL;
    thumbLoader = new Loader();
    thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(thumbURL));
    thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, viewThumbs);
    thumbLoader.name = i.toString();
}

private function viewThumbs(e:Event):void 
{
    thumb = e.target.loader;
    trace(thumb.name);
    if (thumbIndex < VideoList.length()) {
        thumbIndex++;
        loadImage(thumbIndex);
    }
}
```

This code makes your loading synchronously.

Another way: load images as it loaded and sort after loading.

You may add loaded thumb into Array like

```
array.push({id: thumb.name, thumb: thumb.content});
```

When all images will be loaded you need to call

```
array.sortOn("id");
```

And you will have sorted array of images. Then you can add them to stage.
But in this solution you will require some counter anyway to detect when loading ends.

Comment: This worked Great!!! Thanks a lot!!

Can you elaborate more "Another way: load images as it loaded and sort after loading."

Comment: Update answer: add more details for second solution. But I am unsure that it fits you.

Answer (score 0):

This will still try to load them all at once but stores them in order in an array. Once all of the images are loaded you can do something with them.

```
function thumbsLoader(): void {
    videosPending = VideosTotal;
    for (var i: uint = 0; i < VideosTotal; i++) {
        thumbURL = VideoList[i].@THUMB_URL;
        thumbLoader = new Loader();
        thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(thumbURL));
        thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, viewThumbs);
        thumbLoader.name = i.toString();
    }
}
var videosPending = 0;
var videosBack = [];

function viewThumbs(e: Event): void {
    videosBack[Number(e.target.loader.name)] = e.target.loader;
    videosPending--;
    if (videosPending == 0){
      // Now lay them out using the videosBack array
    }
}
```

Comment: Also if you are interested in a really great full featured loader than I would look into this LoaderMax from greensock. Loads lots of file types. http://greensock.com/LoaderMax-AS3

Comment: This is a great solution!! Thanks a lot for all the help!! :))